# Why JPA does not generate automatically an id for my rows?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, orm, java-ee-6

I want to use SEQUENCE strategy for automatically generate ids, but i am breaking my head to make it work. I dont know at all why i cant make it happen.

This is what i do.
First i have an entity:

```
 @Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="VlasnikSeq", sequenceName="VLA_SEQ")
public class Vlasnik implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VlasnikSeq")
    private Long id;
    //...
```

in the persistence.xml i have it mapped:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="sampleAplication">
    <class>entities.Vlasnik</class>
    <class>entities.Ljubimac</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When i use eclipses feature for generating tables for entities i get this:

[image]

As you can see the tables are created, but there is no SEQUENCE table.
I also noticed in the console, the following message, while JPA was creating the tables:

> [EL Warning]: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence
>   Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'VLA_SEQ' does
>   not exist.

The next think i do is try to run the app and see if i can create some rows. But when i try to persist something, i get an exception that says:

> org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: SEQUENCE 'VLA_SEQ' does not

So i  come to the conclusion that for some reason i need that table, so i go to the database management perspective and i try to execute the following query:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE VLA_SEQ;
```

But i get the following message:

> Sequence 'VLA_SEQ' already exists.

I am totally confused. I don't know what should i do. I just want to automatically generate the IDs of my entities when a new row is created in the DB.

It is the first time i use glassfish 3.1, in the version 3.0 i dont remember, having this issue, i could even use just @GenneratedValue. 
Ill appreciate some help.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the ID generation strategy in the @GeneratedValue annotation ?

Comment: @Olivier Croisier Yes i tied AUTO and also SEQUENCE, but didnt work, actually dont really understand what is the difference between each strategy.

Comment: Maybe AUTO defaults to SEQUENCE which does not work well on your setup. Can you try with TABLE and see if it changes anything ?

Comment: AUTO tries to select the "best" strategy for the given database. SEQUENCE uses native sequences (on databases that provide them, ie. Oracle...), and TABLE uses a "standard", "normal" table to emulate a sequence (one column for the name of the sequence, one column for its current value).

Comment: @Olivier Croisier See my question updated, all i did. I still cant make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to use [*GeneratedValue*](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) you have to specify the strategy and the generator. By default the strategy is **AUTO** and the generator is **empty**.

The avaliable strategies are defined by *GenerationType*:

```
public enum GenerationType { TABLE, SEQUENCE, IDENTITY, AUTO };
```

The most common way to use it is by specifying *SEQUENCE* or *IDENTITY*.

- For databases that use *SEQUENCE* such as Oracle and HSQLDB you also have to use *[SequenceGenerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SequenceGenerator.html)* annotation:

  public class MyClass {

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQMYCLASSID")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQMYCLASSID", sequenceName="SEQMYCLASSID")
  private Long id;
  ```

  }

If you have automatic DDL enable you don't have to create the sequence because the JPA provider will do it for you. If that's not the case you have to do it manually like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQMYCLASSID;
```

- For databases that don't use squences and use identity columns such as Microsoft SQL Server you need to specify *IDENTITY* as strategy:

  public class MyClass {

  ```
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)  
  private Long id;
  ```

  }

Comment: I tried the TABLE strategy(I use Derby DB), but don't know why it didn't work(See my update)

Comment: Derby supports sequences since 10.6. I recommend you to use sequences over table generator. If you insist to do it that way here is an example http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/07/29/setting-up-sequential-ids-using-jpa-tablegenerator which requires you to create a table that will act as the table generator.

Comment: I just want to make it work in the easiest way. I just tried with SEQUENCE, as you just suggested, but i got a new exception:

`Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: No current connection.
Error Code: 40000
Call: VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR vlasnikGeneratorName)
Query: ValueReadQuery(sql="VALUES(NEXT VALUE FOR vlasnikGeneratorName)")`

Comment: It also says:`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: SEQUENCE 'VLASNIKGENERATORNAME' does not exist.` 
But the annotations i used this time are:
`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="vlasnikGeneratorName")
 @SequenceGenerator(name="vlasnikGeneratorName", sequenceName="vlasnikGeneratorName")` I noticed this time there is no SEQUENCE table in the DB. I dont understand at all

Comment: Create the squence in the database: CREATE SEQUENCE vlasnikGeneratorName;

Comment: See my question updated, all i did. I still cant make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try specifying this on the class @Table(schema="schemaName"). Where schemaName is the name of your schema.

Comment: I just did,  now i see this exception when i try to insert: `org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Syntax error: Encountered "USER" at line 1, column 13.`

Comment: USER is a reserved keyword in some databases. Use this @Table(name="USERS",schema="schemaName") This way you are telling to the JPA provider to uses USERS as the table for the User entity.